CEFSharp with 2 browser instances and need to delete cookies separately
I have 2 WinForms, each with its own browser instance. Everything is working great but I cant seem to figure out how to clear the cookies for the chosen instance instead of globally.
To set the cache folder
var requestContextSettings1 = new RequestContextSettings
{
    CachePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("DesktopCache") // Path to the cache folder
};
var requestContext1 = new RequestContext(requestContextSettings1);

and
var requestContextSettings2 = new RequestContextSettings
{
    CachePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("MobileCache") // Path to the cache folder
};
var requestContext2 = new RequestContext(requestContextSettings2);

public void ClearBrowserCache()
{
    var requestContext = Cef.GetGlobalRequestContext();
    if (requestContext != null)
        {
        var cookieManager = requestContext.GetCookieManager(null);
        if (cookieManager != null)
        {
            cookieManager.DeleteCookies("", "", new DeleteCookiesCallback());
        }
    }
}

I know the above code gets the global requestcontext, I am just giving an example of what does work globally.
Next I tried something like
var cookieManager = browser.GetCookieManager();
cookieManager.DeleteCookiesAsync();

I even tried deleting the cache folder. Deleting the cache folder didnt seem to clear the session/memory cookies.
Again, seemed to have cleared cookies for both instances. I know this is something simple I am missing. Any chance someone know what it is?

You need to use a unique CachePath for each RequestContext. If you use the same CachePath then they'll share the same cache including cookies.

Sorry I should have included the mobile setting part too.
I do use different cache paths. The problem isnt having separate cookies. That is working fine. Its the deleting of the cookies separately that is the problem.

My problem had something to do with how I was setting the cache file for each RequestContext.
Here is an example of the code that works for me.
    private RequestContext requestContext1;
    private string cachePath1;

    public frmBrowser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Text = title;
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

        // Set cache path
        cachePath1 = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("DesktopCache");
        InitializeBrowser();
    }

    private void InitializeBrowser()
    {
        var requestContextSettings1 = new RequestContextSettings
        {
            CachePath = cachePath1
        };
        requestContext1 = new RequestContext(requestContextSettings1);
        Console.WriteLine(requestContext1 != null ? "RequestContext1 created successfully." : "Failed to create RequestContext1.");

        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("accounts.pch.com/login", requestContext: requestContext1);
        Console.WriteLine(browser != null ? "Browser created successfully." : "Failed to create browser.");

        toolStripContainer.ContentPanel.Controls.Add(browser);

        browser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += OnIsBrowserInitializedChanged;
        browser.LoadingStateChanged += OnLoadingStateChanged;
        browser.ConsoleMessage += OnBrowserConsoleMessage;
        browser.StatusMessage += OnBrowserStatusMessage;
        browser.TitleChanged += OnBrowserTitleChanged;
        browser.AddressChanged += OnBrowserAddressChanged;
        browser.LoadError += OnBrowserLoadError;
        browser.FrameLoadEnd += Browser_FrameLoadEnd;
        browser.JavascriptMessageReceived += JSPostMessageEvents.OnBrowserJavascriptMessageReceived;

        var version = string.Format("Chromium: {0}, CEF: {1}, CefSharp: {2}",
           Cef.ChromiumVersion, Cef.CefVersion, Cef.CefSharpVersion);

#if NETCOREAPP
        var environment = string.Format("Environment: {0}, Runtime: {1}",
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.ProcessArchitecture.ToString().ToLowerInvariant(),
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription);
#else
        var bitness = Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86";
        var environment = String.Format("Environment: {0}", bitness);
#endif

        DisplayOutput(string.Format("{0}, {1}", version, environment));
    }

    private void ClearCookies(IRequestContext requestContext, string url = "", string cookieName = "")
    {
        if (requestContext == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RequestContext is null.");
            return;
        }

        var cookieManager = requestContext.GetCookieManager(null);
        if (cookieManager == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CookieManager is null.");
            return;
        }

        var task = cookieManager.DeleteCookiesAsync(url, cookieName);
        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsCompleted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cookies cleared for the given RequestContext.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to clear cookies: " + t.Exception?.Message);
            }
        });
    }

Repeat code adjustments for mobile (2nd instance)
Now the cache is being set properly and I am able to reset the cookies based off the RequestContext.
If wondering, what I did is did a listcookie function which was printing nothing. Set a test cookie programmatically, and listcookies was listing the test cookie. This allowed me to realize my problem was how I was setting cache folder and hence tried this method to define the cache paths as class-level fields to ensure they are correctly referenced.

It seems to me you would have to load each form each in its own AppDomain and initialize each instance with different cache directories.  Then you can clear each instance's cache separately.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you elaborate on that or provide a (working) example? Right now your suggestions are hard to put into practice.

CefSharp only runs in the default AppDomain, it cannot be run in non-default appdomains. It's clear you've not run/tested your answer.
